# Create aws rds instance using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create an RDS instance on AWS using terraform, and getting the following error

Is this code ok?

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}


resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet1" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet2" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db-subnet" {
  name       = "DB subnet group"
  subnet_ids = ["${aws_subnet.private-subnet1.id}", "${aws_subnet.private-subnet2.id}"]
}


resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
  allocated_storage    = "20"
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7.22"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "admin"
  password             = "admin"
  parameter_group_name = "db-mysql"
  db_subnet_group_name = "db-subnet"
}
```

I get this error while I terraform apply

```
Error: Error creating DB Subnet Group: DBSubnetGroupDoesNotCoverEnoughAZs: DB Subnet Group doesn't meet availability zone coverage requirement. Please add subnets to cover at least 2 availability zones. Current coverage: 1
    status code: 400, request id: 1bc7f2db-3ad7-41d9-93d0-6cbe3c0adfec

  on terraform.tf line 24, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db-subnet":
  24: resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db-subnet" {



Error: Error creating DB Instance: DBSubnetGroupNotFoundFault: DBSubnetGroup 'db-subnet' not found.
    status code: 404, request id: a4264af9-c9ac-4241-993f-e8c62e348247

  on terraform.tf line 30, in resource "aws_db_instance" "db":
  30: resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
```

Answer (score 5):

The errors are pretty clear about the problems, so let's break them down.

The first error has to do with the fact that you aren't specifying an [availability zone](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/subnet.html#availability_zone) when you create each of your subnets. A db subnet group must span at least 2 az's for high availability and you're not specifying az's for your subnets so they're getting created in the same one. Add an `availability_zone` parameter to both subnets using different az's from whatever region you're using.

```terraform
resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet1" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "<an az from your region>"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet2" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "<a different az from your region>"
}
```

The second error is related to the fact that in your `aws_db_instance`, you don't reference the subnet group resource that you are creating and instead you're specifying a hardcoded subnet group by name. Terraform isn't aware of the dependency and uses the non-existent one in parallel while trying to create the one you've defined. Change it to

```terraform
db_subnet_group_name = "${aws_db_subnet_group.db-subnet.name}"
```

and that 2nd error will go away, then you can resolve the first issue.